# Factory Design Pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am trying to implement Factory Design Pattern and have done this far till now.

```
import abc

class Button(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    html = ""
    def get_html(self, html):
        return self.html

class ButtonFactory():
    def create_button(self, type):
        baseclass = Button()
        targetclass = type.baseclass.capitalize()
        return targetclass

button_obj = ButtonFactory()
button = ['image', 'input', 'flash']
for b in button:
    print button_obj.create_button(b).get_html()
```

The output should be the HTML of all your button types.

I get the error like this

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'baseclass'
```

I am trying to implement a class which has different variations, such as ImageButton, InputButton and FlashButton. Depending on the place, it may need to create different html for the buttons

Comment: Well, you pass a string (such as `'image'`) as the argument to `create_button()`. Perhaps you meant to pass `image` (a reference to an actual class that has a `baseclass` attribute).

Comment: you also use `get_html` with no arguments while it require 1 (except `self`).
it is not clear what you're trying to do from your code.

Comment: @Elisha I am trying to implement a class which has different variations, such as ImageButton, InputButton and FlashButton. Depending on the place, it may need to create different html for the buttons.

Comment: Your question has already been answered but I still wanted to say that using a class when a plain function would do is quite unpythonic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are trying to call `baseclass` attribute of `str`, which does not exist, because `b` gets string values (one of `['image', 'input', 'flash']`).
If you want to create an object according to a string representing its name, you can use the `globals()` dictionary, which holds a mapping between variable names and their values.

```
class Button(object):
    html = ""
    def get_html(self):
        return self.html

class Image(Button):
    html = "<img></img>"

class Input(Button):
    html = "<input></input>"

class Flash(Button):
    html = "<obj></obj>"

class ButtonFactory():
    def create_button(self, typ):
        targetclass = typ.capitalize()
        return globals()[targetclass]()

button_obj = ButtonFactory()
button = ['image', 'input', 'flash']
for b in button:
    print button_obj.create_button(b).get_html()
```

EDIT:
Using `globals()` or `locals()` is also not a good practice so, if you can, it is better to create a mapping between the relevant objects and their names, like this:

```
button_objects = {'image':Image,'flash':Flash,'input':Input}
```

and replace `create_button` with:

```
def create_button(self, typ):        
    return button_objects[typ]()
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend creating a dictionary that explicitly maps, e.g., `'image'` to `Image`, rather than do it dynamically with `eval`. Or better yet, just use `button = [ Image, Input, Flash ]`: classes are first-class objects which can be stored in a list.

Comment: thanks, I fixed the code to use `globals()` which is safer and keep the ability to use strings. but I agree that using list of objects or dictionary that map between strings and objects is much better.

Comment: I'm not sure using global variables is an improvement.

Comment: can you explain why? and `locals()`? anyway, I added your advice in the answer, thanks.

Comment: there's a typo in the last line. should be `return button_objects[typ]()` not `buttun_objects`. But it's too small a change for an edit apparently.

Comment: credit your sources: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_design_patterns/python_design_patterns_factory.htm. Even if it's you.

Comment: If I were to split each of the classes in this post into their own `.py` file, then this won't work because those modules are not loaded. And you'll get `KeyError` on line `globals()[targetclass]()`

Answer (score 5):

As of 2021, the accepted answer could be improved in multiple ways because Python has evolved (`3.9.x`). The same applies to its uncredited [original source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_design_patterns/python_design_patterns_factory.htm#:%7E:text=The%20factory%20pattern%20comes%20under,object%20using%20a%20common%20interface).

First of all, the implementation of an object factory is tightly bound to the notion of an [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming). According to the [Gang of Four definition of the Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) we read that it should:

> Define an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide
> which class to instantiate. The factory method lets a class defer
> instantiation to subclasses.

Having said that, some essential improvements of the accepted answer could be the following:

1. The base class `Button` should be an abstract class to define the interface. In other words, it should inherit from `abc.ABC`.
2. We see that the only difference between the children (`Flash`, `Image`, `Input`) is the value of the `self.html` attribute in each case and not the actual implementation of the `get_html` method. This means that the `self.html` attribute should be abstract, i.e. a part of the interface. A very neat way of defining attributes is via the built-in `@property` decorator. Thus, an abstract attribute would be decorated using both `@abc.abstractmethod` and `@property` on its "getter" method. This is important, because it will raise an exception if the "getter" method is not implemented inside the body of the child class, effectively adhering to the interface specifications.
3. The `ButtonFactory.create_button` method is **unnecessary**. In fact, it is also unnecessary to instantiate a ButtonFactory, whose exclusive purpose is to yield child objects. Instead, you could migrate the creation of a child object within the constructor of a `ButtonFactory`, i.e. inside the `__new__` method. This would yield directly a child object at the instantiation of the factory.
4. Finally, we can put all buttons under the same namespace (`Buttons` class) to avoid using `globals` when looking for any of the children buttons.

Putting everything together in a `buttons.py` file:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Buttons:
    class Button(ABC):
        @property
        @abstractmethod
        def html(self) -> str:
            raise NotImplementedError

    class Flash(Button):
        html = "<obj></obj>"

    class Image(Button):
        html = "<img></img>"

    class Input(Button):
        html = "<input></input>"


class ButtonFactory:
    def __new__(cls, button_type: str) -> Buttons.Button:
        return getattr(Buttons, button_type)()
```

In this way, we could instantiate any button-like object as:

```py
from buttons import ButtonFactory

flash_button = ButtonFactory("Flash")
image_button = ButtonFactory("Image")
input_button = ButtonFactory("Input")

print(flash_button.html, image_button.html, input_button.html)
```

and the output would be:

```
<obj></obj> <img></img> <input></input>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is where your error comes from:

```
button = ['image', 'input', 'flash'] # button contains strings

for b in button: # b is a string

create_button(b) # argument 'type' is a string

type.baseclass... # hence the AttributeError
```

Your list `button` needs to contain objects that have the `baseclass` attribute, not their names as strings. Also, you shouldn't use `type` as a variable name, as it shadows a Python standard library function `type()`.

Comment: Ok, i understood but can you provide a example plz.

Comment: Not really, I don't know what your objects are!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you need to create button instances based on a runtime string, an alternative to your Button class and factory would be to simply have a dictionary of names to types (much as chepner suggested):

```
buttonTypes = {"image" : Image,
               "input": Input,
               "flash" : Flash}

button = buttonTypes[name]()
print button.html
```

(nb this was typed straight into here, there may be some mistakes in the detail). Because Python is duck-typed you may well not need a base type.

Comment: Square brackets do not construct a dictionary in Python, curly brackets do.