# staticmethod vs classmethod for factory pattern when using pydantic

Tags: python, design-patterns, static, pydantic

Reading most questions with *@classmethod vs @staticmethod*, replies state that static is almost useless in python except to logically group functions, but module can do the work.

But I ended up with a factory pattern, using pydantic, where I cannot see how we can replace the static method with a class method.
Without pydantic, one would put the logic for object instanciation in `__init__()` constructor.
Using pydantic, I ended up to create a factory like `build_static()` (that will call some logic, `init3x()` here)

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class A(BaseModel):
    text: str
    uid: int

    @staticmethod
    def build_static(text, uid):
        a = A(text=text, uid=uid)
        a.init3x()
        a.show()
        return a

    def init3x(self):
        self.text *= 3
        print(self.text)

    @classmethod
    def show(cls):
        print(cls.text, cls.uid)

    @classmethod
    def build(cls, text, uid):
        cls.uid = uid
        cls.text = text
        cls.init3x(cls)
        cls.show()
        return cls
```

My question is: is `build_static()` as good pattern, using a static method ? If not, what is the right way ?

Note 1: class method `build()` seems a wrong pattern in this case, since there is a logic that should only apply to each instance independently (`init3x()` in my example)

```
a = A.build('test ', 1)
b = A.build('test B ', 2)
c = A.build_static('test C ', 3)
d = A.build_static('test D ', 4)
a.text, b.text, c.text, d.text
> ('test B test B test B ',
  'test B test B test B ',
  'test C test C test C ',
  'test D test D test D ')
```

Which is not what you want with a factory for instances a and b.

Note 2: `cls.init3x(cls)` looks highly anti-pythonic to me.

UPDATE:
Seems staticmethod for factory is seen as default pattern in this book [Python3 patterns idioms](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html)

Comment: This all looks very strange to me. The term _factory_ typically refers to a function that constructs and returns a **class**. Your `build_static` method is not that; it just returns an **instance** of `A`. `init3x` is just a regular old instance method that mutates the `text` field value. Your `build` method is _also_ decidedly not a factory because it does not construct a class, it just mutates the same existing `A` class and **it breaks the Pydantic model in the process**.

Comment: My question is: What is it that you _actually_ want to achieve here? Because this is 100% an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What do you want `A` to do? Or what do you want your "factory" for `A` to do? If you could ignore the `staticmethod`/`classmethod` question for a moment and really explain what the purpose of that class and those methods should be, that might help others understand your problem and provide a useful solution.

Comment: Re-reading your description, is the real goal here just to modify the initially provided `text` field value during instantiation?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg aren't factories supposed to return instances? I am basing that on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025959/factory-design-pattern

Comment: @python_user Maybe you're right and I was thinking of a special kind of factory (a class factory). In that case I retract my objection to the term. It is still unclear to me what OP is actually trying to achieve because even if that is what he is aiming for, neither of his methods work for that pattern.

Comment: Yes, factory can return instances. @DaniilFajnberg that's what I want to achive. Here init3x is just an exemple, my real world use-case is a A.load() where load() query a DB and instantiate an object. So I want a .build() factory that creates the object from params with its logic (as a constructor would do) and a loac() factory that would return the same result but with data taken from DB.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to have a constructor for `A` that takes the provided initial `text` field value and modifies it (like multiplying it by 3), three distinct simple approaches come to mind.

---

### A) Override the `__init__` method

The first option is just to put that modification logic into the `__init__` method.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class A(BaseModel):
    text: str
    uid: int
    
    def __init__(self, text: str, uid: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(text=text * 3, uid=uid)
```

##### Pros

- Straightforward and fairly transparent

##### Cons

- Harder to maintain, if model fields change.
- Unexpected behavior because a user passing a `text` argument to the `__init__` method expects that value to end up on the model instance (and not something else).
- No validation of the `text` argument before calling the parent class' `__init__`, which means the modification operation might fail or cause unexpected results, if some other type is passed.

##### Usage

```py
# As expected:
a = A(text="foo", uid=123)
print(a)  # text='foofoofoo' uid=123

# Oops:
a = A(text=1, uid=123)
print(a)  # text='3' uid=123
```

---

### B) Alternative constructor

Alternatively, you can write a custom constructor that looks essentially the same as the `__init__` method and exists alongside it. Here we actually decorate it as a `classmethod` because we are using the class inside the method.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from pydantic import BaseModel


class A(BaseModel):
    text: str
    uid: int

    @classmethod
    def custom_constructor(cls, text: str, uid: int) -> A:
        return cls(text=3 * text, uid=uid)
```

##### Pros

- Clear to the user that the behavior is different from what he would expect of the regular constructor (the `__init__` method).

##### Cons

- Hard to maintain (same as the previous solution).
- No pre-validation (same as above)

##### Usage

```py
a = A.custom_constructor(text="foo", uid=123)
print(a)  # text='foofoofoo' uid=123
```

---

### C) Custom validator

We can simply define a regular [validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/) for the `text` field that does the modification during initialization.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class A(BaseModel):
    text: str
    uid: int

    @validator("text")
    def text_times_3(cls, v: str) -> str:
        return v * 3
```

##### Pros

- Concise (utilizing Pydantic capabilities)
- Very convenient to maintain because it is unrelated to other model fields
- Default validation of the initial `text` value ensures our custom validator will really deal with a `str`

##### Cons

- Potentially unexpected for users because the `text` argument will be modified before ending up on the model field (same as the first solution).

##### Usage

```py
# As expected:
a = A(text="foo", uid=123)
print(a)  # text='foofoofoo' uid=123

# Also as expected:
a = A(text=1, uid=123)
print(a)  # text='111' uid=123
```